# Unable to connect to Gmail, using php imap

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I'm trying to use imap with php to retrieve mails from gmail using the following code:

```
<?php
  $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
  $username = 'myaccount@gmail.com';
  $password = 'mypassword';
  $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) 
         or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
?>
```

However, imap_last_error throws me the following error:

"Unable to create TCP socket: Address family not supported by protocol"

I have imap enabled on my gmail account. imap 2007e with ssl (and OpenSSL) and kerberos seems to be enabled on the webserver. I don't have control on the domains ports, but support told me "Outgoing IMAP connections can be made, this is not blocked.".

I see I'm not the only one having trouble connecting to gmail using IMAP. However, I didn't find anyone who encountered this error.

Comment: Try pinging imap.gmail.com and replacing the hostname with the IP (currently, I get `64.233.171.109`).  *This is a temporary test, not a solution.*  If it works with the IP address, then my guess is that something is misconfigured with your DNS / IPv6 setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I replaced the hostname with 64.233.165.109, 64.233.165.108 (which I got when I pinged imap.gmail.com) and 64.233.171.109. All of them resulted in a "connection timed out" message. Is this information useful to you?

Comment: I think Google is having some server issues at the moment.